# mysql query returns up to 65535 rows

Tags: mysql

MySQL query returns up to 65535 rows (max). How can retrieve all the rows of a table over the limit? (totally 120k)

```
        query_string1 = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table1"                                  
        print query_string1
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query_string1)
            self.ids = self.cursor.fetchall()
            print "Select query was successfully executed"
            print "%d unique ids where retrieved" %len(self.ids)
```

Comment: Where are you running this query?  The 65535 looks awfully familiar to the Excel row limit.

Comment: what do you mean? i run this query through a python script. DB engine: InnoDB

Comment: How many rows are returned if you execute in MySQL?

Comment: @Zane it returns 65535 again

Comment: @zuperakos Are you sure that you have `120k` distinct ids?  If you remove the distinct what is the result?  Try running `select count(id), count(distinct id) from table1` to see what the result is.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is probably stemming from the fact that you have a `DISTINCT` on your `SELECT` statement. You may have 120K rows in that table however that does not necessarily mean there are that many distinct ID's in that table. If you are doing a `SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table1` directly in MySQL and getting back 65535 rows, then there are only 65535 distinct ID's in that table. If you remove the distinct you will see all 120K however many of them will be duplicate ID's

EDIT: If you remove the `DISTINCT` and you still only receive 65535 rows when running the query in MySQL then that's all the rows you have.

Comment: Without DISTINCT return again 65535. Sorry not working...

Comment: @zuperakos why do you think there are 120k rows?

Comment: @zuperakos What if you do a `SELECT COUNT(*) From table1` using MySQL what is the result?

Comment: There are 120k rows! 120pages of 1000 rows (navicat)

Comment: @zuperakos is that what returns when you `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1`?